# Radius of Convergence and Interval of Convergence help

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I had a bit of a problem with a question I had.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{n}(x-5)^{n}$$

While looking for the radius and interval of convergence through the ratio test I ended up with $|x-5| \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}$, this is where I got stuck because I couldn't find the limit, could anyone give me some tips or help me on this? I think I tried applying L'hospitals rule but might've ended up doing it wrong.

Comment: I edited your post to (1) make the math a little more readable (typeset with mathjax) and (2) to type the sum instead of linking to an image.  Since you are new, you should look at the math formatting guide: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.  I typeset the problem (removing the image) because links break over time and the image is not text searchable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the root test.

$$\rho(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \root{n} \of{|n^n (x-5)^n|}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} n|x-5|.$$

This limit is infinite unless $x = 5.$  The radius of convergence is $0$.

Comment: That is certainly easier in this case then the ratio test.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Write $\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^{n}}$ as $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}(n+1)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}(n+1)$.  Then all you really need to know about $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ is that its limit is bigger than $0$.

Comment: What you need to know about $(1+\frac 1 n)^n$ is that its LIMIT is bigger than $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, true... and it is.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test and the root test get used in similar situations, but if you see $n$ in both the base and the exponent of the same exponential expression (e.g. $n^{2n}$), then that is a pretty good indication that the root test will be more efficient.